# C string separation

Tags: c, string, char, divide

I looked at related topics, tried some of the examples and didn't found anything that helps me.

I am taking a string for input eg char str[50]
it has the following format Remove 1 1 
Remove can be another word which has different length
the number of integers could be more than 2 
I need each part of the string to be stored in different variables for the numeric values int if possible

I tried with strcmp stracat strtok strstr but apparently I am missing something

```
char str[] = "Remove 2 3 2";
char * pch;
char split[50];
printf("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n", str);
pch = strtok(str, " ");
while (pch != NULL) {
    printf("%s\n", pch);
    strcat(split,pch);
    printf("\nThe string is %s",split);
    pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

This is my latest attempt. What I'm trying to do is to remove the space characters, then probably I could identify the word behind Remove e.g. if it is remove or it is some other word with strstr. But How to get the numeric values separated? And this is my output how to get rid of these characters

```
    The string is ��_o�Remove2

    The string is ��_o�Remove23

    The string is ��_o�Remove232

    The string is ��_o�Remove232
```

Comment: that removed the chars thanks @user3121023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand you may be wanted each string component into a separate variable, then why not using an array instead ??

just check for space and ignore them

```
  char str[] = "hi 1 2 3";
    char store[100];
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i = 0,j = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++){
        if(str[i] != 32) {   // value of space is 32
                store[j] = str[i];
                j++;
        }
    }

    for( i = 0; i < strlen(store); i++){
        printf("%c\n",store[i]);
    }
```

**output :**

```
h
i
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

strcat concatenates. I believe what you want is get the splitted parts one by one, and not concatenate them.

So you better try something like this:

```
char split[MAX_NUM_TOKENS][50];
int num_tokens = 0;
```

And instead of strcat, use something like:

```
strcpy(split[num_tokens], *pch);
printf("The string is %s\n",split[num_tokens]);
num_tokens++;
```

Comment: I think I did what you said and I only got printed The string is Remove several times [link]http://pastebin.com/mn337qXY

Comment: Ok i've actually got segmentation fault

Comment: @ThomasJeffrey Yes. the strcpy should have 'pch' instead of '*pch'. My bad.